# ANDROID, what layout elements should I use?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make an android layout like this one.

[image]

1. tile background all over the screen.
2. top menu which, overlays the background ( note the shadow ).
3. some sort of a table with text options, maybe pictures, which can be scrolled up and down.
4. bottom menu, which appears by sliding up after a menu button is hit.

What kind of layout elements do you think I should use for that?

Thanks!

Comment: An image illustrating this will be much helpful

Comment: there is an image above. if it doesn't load, here's a duplicate: http://skyeye.cc/m.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should first learn about the Android Layout and XML layout design, then you can easily prepare this layout as well.

**`Relative Layout`** will be the better layout as compare to other layouts like Linear Layout and Table Layout.

To display middle part that is showing textual description may contains **`ListView`** (ListView because as you have mentioned Text Options should scroll up and down), but it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The `RelativeLayout` is the most flexible, and I think you can make all this with a minimal hierarchy view depth.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use a RelativeLayout. The Top Menu bar could be a custom class which extends a LinearLayout and this can be used in the RelativeLayout (in fact in any screen you have to provide UI consistency). Similarly, the bottom menu would be a custom control containing the appropriate animations. The rest of the screen would be contained in a ScrollView, possibly containing a TableLayout. I have something very similar using a MapView in the main screen and it works fine.